# Donut plot with echatr and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, rcharts

I have the following data and I need to make a graph similar to the one I made in tableau

```
df<-data.frame(estado=c("Aprobado","Reprobado"),
               freq=c(551,7),
             porcentaje=c(0.99,1))
```

The graph with echatr looks like this

```
df %>% 
    head() %>% 
    mutate(estado = row.names(.)) %>% 
    e_charts(estado) %>% 
    e_pie(freq, radius = c("50%", "70%")) %>% 
    e_title("Donut chart")
```

[image]

I don't understand why I can't put the labels or titles right.

with ggplot2 I have the following way

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=2,y=porcentaje, fill=estado))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color="white")+
  geom_text(aes(label=percent(porcentaje/100)),
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color="white",size=6)+
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("salmon","steelblue"))+
  theme_void()+
  labs(title="Gráfico de Dona")+
  xlim(0.5,2.5)
```

[image]

I don't like how this graph looks, its hue looks very poor and aesthetically bad and I'm looking for a result similar to the one I did in Tableau even with the center label

[image]

Hopefully someone could tell me how it would be better to do it so that its shade is right in either of the two codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colours by changing the `values` argument in `scale_fill_manual()`.

Placing the text in the middle can be done with `annotate()`, setting the `x = -Inf` and `y = -Inf` will place it in the middle.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df<-data.frame(estado=c("Aprobado","Reprobado"),
               freq=c(551,7),
               porcentaje=c(0.99,1))

ggplot(df,aes(x=2,y=porcentaje, fill=estado))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color="white")+
  geom_text(aes(label=percent(porcentaje/100)),
            position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color="white",size=6)+
  annotate(
    "text", x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = paste0("Total\n", sum(df$freq))
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#75A1C7","#F9A655"))+
  theme_void()+
  labs(title="Gráfico de Dona")+
  xlim(0.5,2.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: because it looks like 50 and 50 if it is 90 /10?

Comment: That is what is in the data, I didn't make that up

Comment: yes I'm sorry I already saw the error